# sum of perpendicular distances from the sides of a triangle.

Tags: geometry

I am trying to solve a problem and got stuck in the following:-

[image]

P, A’, C’ are respectively points on the sides AC, CB, and AB of ⊿ABC. PA’ and PC’ are the perpendiculars to the sides of the triangle such that S = PA’ + PC’. Inside ⊿ABC, find a point Q (its locus would be even better) such that its sum of the perpendiculars to the side AB and side BC is equal to S.

If the above is not possible, particular solution (with conditions restricted/relaxed) is also welcome.

Comment: Is $S$ a given, constant, positive real number, with point $P$ chosen so your expression for $S$ is true? Or was $S$ derived from the point $P$?

Comment: @RoryDaulton S depends on the location of the fixed point P but P is on the line segment of AC.

Answer (score 1):

Such a locus is a line segment: if $Q_A,Q_B,Q_C$ are the projections of a point $Q$ (inside $ABC$) on the sides $BC,AC,AB$ of the triangle, then:
$$ QQ_A\cdot BC + QQ_B\cdot AC+QQ_C\cdot AB = 2[ABC]$$
holds, no matter where $Q$ is placed inside $ABC$. So, just find another point $P'$ on the perimeter of $ABC$ such that the sum of the distances from the sides $AB,BC$ equals $S$, and connect it with $P$: this will be your wanted locus. If you take *signed* distances, then the locus is the whole $PP'$-line.

If you like to use coordinate geometry, just put a skew reference system with centre in $B$ and the $x$-axis and $y$-axis oriented like $BA$ and $BC$. You are just solving $x+y=S$, that is the equation of a line.

[image]

Comment: P' is a kind of hard to find. Is there any method that can locate P' explicitly?

Comment: @Mick: there are plenty. For instance, increase the distance from $AB$ by a small amount $h$ and decrease the distance from $BC$ by the same small amount. You will find a point on the $PP'$ line, that is enough to draw the line.

Comment: Mine is more or less like yours. The question is now: How to prove that any point on PP' has the required sum equal to S?

Comment: @Mick: you know in advance that the locus is a line segment - see the last part about the skew reference system - hence once two points on it are found, we're done.

Comment: @Mick: so the sum equal $S$ in $P$ and $P'$, but not on the line joining them? I really doubt it, please check your construction. It is trivial that the locus is a line, and if you find two points on such a line, every point between them (on the line) belongs to the locus.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I have successfully located a point Q = P’ such that its sum of distances from AB and AC is S.

[image]

(1) Let PC’ = min(PC’, PA’).

(2) Draw a circle centered at P and radius = PC’.

(3) Extend A’P to cut the circle at X.

(4) Translate A’X sideways until it hits AB at P’ and BC at Y.

For the point P’, its sum of distances from AB and from BC

= 0 + P’Y = PY’ = XA’ = XP + PA’ = PC’ + PA’ = S.

P and P’ are now jointed.

According to the suggestion: any point on PP’ meets the said requirement. How to prove this is true?